# C++ Stack Calulator and error reading characters of a string

Tags: c++, stack, calculator, rpn

Hello Im new to programming and I'm trying to make a RPN calculator in Cpp. I sort of understand how it works but i dont know how to code it. So after searching on youtube i found a video of someone with a Stack calulator im planning to use on my project. I copied everything the program runs but it doesnt display the desired result. I debugged on Visual Studio and it gives me the error {data=0xcccccccccccccccc  top=-858993460 size=-858993460 }. The program keeps running but doesnt do what it is supposed to do. any help would be appreciate it.

**This is the firs file that defines the stack**

```
#pragma once
// arraystack.h

#define STACK_H

template <class T>
class stack
{
private:
    T* data; // Pointer.
    int top;
    int size;
    void resize();
    bool needToResize();

public:
    stack()
    {
        size = 5;
        data = new T[size];
        top = 0;
    }
    void push(T item);
    T peek();
    T pop();
    bool isEmpty();
};

//#include "arraystack.cpp"
#include <stdexcept> // para manejar la excepcion de fuera de rango.


template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T item)
{
    if (needToResize())
        resize();
    data[top] = item;
    top++;
}

template < class T >
T stack<T>::peek()
{
    if (top <= 0)
        throw std::out_of_range("Attempting to peek an empty stack.");
    return data[top - 1];
}

template<class T>
T stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (top <= 0)
        throw std::out_of_range("Attempting to pop an empty stack.");
    top--;
    return data[top];
}

template <class T>
bool stack<T>::needToResize()
{
    return (top == size);// si top es igual al size entonce sse necesita resize.
}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::resize()
{
    T* newdata = new T[2 * size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        newdata[i] = data[i];
    data = newdata;
    size *= 2;
}

template <class T>
bool stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return (top == 0);
}
```

**This is the second file that defines the calculator**

```
#pragma once
// calculator.h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "arraystack.h"

using namespace std;

// check if char is a digit.
bool isDigit(char c)
{
    return (c <= '0' && c <= '9'); // valor unicode de los numeros en 48 empieza 0.
}

//check if char is an operator
bool isOp(char c)
{
    return (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '^');
}

// determine the precedence of an operator
int getPrecendence(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-': return 1;
    case '*':
    case '/': return 2;
    case '(':
    case ')': return 3;
    default: return -1;
    }
}

// evaluate an arithmetic expression.
int operate(int val1, int val2, char op)
{
    if (op == '+') return val1 + val2;
    if (op == '-') return val1 - val2;
    if (op == '*') return val1 * val2;
    return val1 / val2; // se retorna esta porque es la unica op left. (sin expo)
}

//evaluate a string.
int evaluate(string s)
{
    stack<int> vals;
    stack<char> ops;

    int val = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    while (pos < s.length())
    {
        char spot = s[pos];
        if (isDigit(spot))
        {
            val = (val * 10) + (int)(spot - '0');
        }
        else if (isOp(spot))
        {
            if (spot == '(')
            {
                ops.push(spot);
                val = 0;
            }
            else if (vals.isEmpty())
            {
                vals.push(val);
                ops.push(spot);
                val = 0;
            }
            else if (spot == ')')
            {
                vals.push(val);
                while (ops.peek() != '(')
                {
                    spot = ops.pop();
                    val = vals.pop();
                    int prev = vals.pop(); // previous on the stack
                    val = operate(prev, val, spot);
                    vals.push(val);
                }
                ops.pop();
                vals.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                char prev = ops.peek();
                if (getPrecendence(spot) > getPrecendence(prev))
                {
                    vals.push(val);
                    ops.push(spot);
                    val = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int prevval = vals.pop();
                    int prevop = ops.pop();
                    prevval = operate(prevval, val, prevop);
                    vals.push(prevval);
                    ops.push(spot);
                    val = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }

    while (!ops.isEmpty())
    {
        int prev = vals.pop();
        char spot = ops.pop();
        val = operate(prev, val, spot);
    }
    return val;
}
```

**This is the file that tests**

```
// arraystack.cpp (the tester class)
#include <iostream>
#include "calculator.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << evaluate("3 + 4 + 5") << endl; //  expected result 12
    cout << evaluate("3 * 4 + 5") << endl; // expected result 17
    cout << evaluate("3 + 4 * 5") << endl; // expected result 23
    cout << evaluate("(3 +4) * 5") << endl; // expected result 35
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**The results i get**
[Results after running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xubJg.png)

**The errors showing in the visual studio debugger**
[Visual Studio Debbuging screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3dw.png)

I have no idea of whats going on. Any help would be appreciate it.
The output i get:
-1667666
-1667666
-1667666
-9658676
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Did you try **stepping through** your code, **line-by-line**, with said debugger, taking note when the values in the variables, don't match your expectations?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i believe i did. did you check the picture i uploaded? it assigns some unexpected values to the variables.

Comment: @DeiDei i believe it copies when assigning data = newdata; but the functing isnt in use in the code yet.

Comment: @MiguelArturoSanchezCuello I didn't ask if you "ran the code with a debugger attached, until it stopped". I asked if you stepped through the code, line-by-line, manually, while investigating the values of variables, at each step?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius. Sorry i couldnt understand at first... yes i ran the code line-by-line. the code is actually from a youtube video but for some reason it doesnt work for me.

Comment: "ran line-by-line", and "stepped through line-by-line" implies different things. Did you actually stopped, at each line, looked at the values of variables, at each step? Stepped into the functions, not over them? Stepping through the code with a debugger is how all developers solve the problems of their code not working. The sooner you will learn how to use it, the better you will be, in the long run. Related reading material: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If you did what @AlgirdasPreidžius is asking you to do, you should at least be able to tell us at which line of your code the variable got its unexpected value, what the value was before that line how, the stack trace looks at that point and what values the other local variables had at that point.

Comment: Note: When you find a highly regular address or error code like 0xcccccccccccccccc or a weird-looking decimal number like -858993460 odds are good that the computer is trying to tell you something. Convert the decimal to hex (0XCCCCCCCC again) and [look up what that code means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values). CCCCCCCC is a common PC debugger code for uninitialized stack memory.

Comment: @user4581301 right below that it says unable to read memory. it seems like the error is in line 49 and 50 when creating the two stacks in the calculator.h file i till have not figure out what is wrong with it...

Again this is a code i copied from a youtube video mine is exactly as the other person is.. the only difference is that im running windows with visual and he was running in linux with g++

Comment: Typo:  `return (c <= '0' && c <= '9');` should be `return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');` Could be more bugs in there, but that's the one that jumps out at me.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you very much! that was the issue. and thanks for the additional info

Comment: If you had stepped through the `isDigit` function like @AlgirdasPreidžius was suggesting, though he didn't point exactly at where the problem was, you probably would have found the bug an hour ago. The debugger is one of the best programmer productivity tools out there. The sooner you get used to using it, the more time you'll have to become a better programmer.

Comment: @user4581301 and the worst part is that i went back to the video to check... the guy had it right i copied it wrong... again thank you all guys you all were very helpful. i read the article Algirdas sent me and im going to study to do that before i code.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah i know he was right i was just a little mindblocked

Comment: I do appreciate your time guys. now ill keep on studying i hope one day ill be able to answer questions like you guys do.